# PHP MySQL - Code generator using different table records

Tags: php, mysql, system, generator

Me again,

In this case I have an accountingcode table [ACCOUNTINGCODE] with the fields:
ACC1CUST (example: IVMA)
ACC2DATE (example: 12)
ACC3NROFPROJ (example: 05)
ACC4USER (example: JD)

Let me explain.
These is the example of an accountingcode:
IVMA-12-01-JD
IVMA-12-02-RP
IVMA-12-03-WD
IVMA-12-04-JD

ACC1CUST is filled with a NAMECODE of a [CUSTOMER].
ACC2DATE are the 2 end numbers of the year the [ACCOUNTINGCOE] is made by the user.
ACC3NROFPROJ is the number of projects of the same [CUSTOMER] in the same year. So ACC1CUST, ACC2DATE and ACC3NROFPROJ depend on each other.
ACC4USER is the NAMECODE of the [EXECUTOR] so this is not so important here.

I made a generator query. This generator counts +1 on the MAX projects which he has in the [ACCOUNTINGCODE]. But my code isn't depending on the the year (ACC2DATE). So if I already have IVMA-12-01-JD and next I place IVMA-13 it won't start over at 01, but continues at 02. Ofcourse, because my code is checking the amount of projects of the ACC1CUST.

My query is:

```
$projectcount="
SELECT accountingcode.custid, customer.custid, MAX(acc3nrofproj) as 'projects'
FROM accountingcode, customer
WHERE accountingcode.custid= customer.custid
AND customer.custid = '$custid'
";

$result3=mysql_query($projectcount) or die("query fout " . mysql_error() );
while( $record3=mysql_fetch_array($result3) )
{
$projectcount=$record3['projects'];
$projectcount = $projectcount+1;
$format = '%1$03s';
$formatprojectcount = sprintf($format, $projectcount);
}
```

But this doesn't make any difference if you start a new year which doesn't exists already in ACC2DATE.

Anyone any idea how I can make this work?

Thank you alot in advance!

FOUND IT

```
    $projectcount="
      SELECT accountingcode.custid, accountingcode.acc2date, MAX(acc3nrofproj) as 'projects'
      FROM accountingcode, customer
      WHERE accountingcode.custid= customer.custid
      AND customer.custid = '$custid'
      AND acc2date = '$formatdatefrom'
      ";

    $result3=mysql_query($projectcount) or die("query fout " . mysql_error() );
    while( $record3=mysql_fetch_array($result3) )
    {
        $projectcount=$record3['projects'];
        $projectcount = $projectcount+1;
        $format = '%1$03s';
        $formatprojectcount = sprintf($format, $projectcount);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for($i = $startYear/*03, Let's say.*/; i <= $endYear /*12?*/; i++)
{

    $projectcount="SELECT accountingcode.custid, customer.custid, MAX(acc3nrofproj) as 'projects'
      FROM accountingcode, customer
      WHERE accountingcode.custid= customer.custid
      AND customer.custid = '$custid'
      AND ACC2DATE = $i";

    $result3=mysql_query($projectcount) or die("query fout " . mysql_error() );
    while( $record3=mysql_fetch_array($result3) )
    {
        $projectcount=$record3['projects'];
        $projectcount = $projectcount+1;
        $format = '%1$03s';
        $formatprojectcount = sprintf($format, $projectcount);
    }
}
```

Use the above query in a for loop starting from a baseYear to the final year.

Comment: I idd was thinking about doing it in a loop but i was thinking like from 2012 to i dont know, 2500? Idd, from base to end is a little more ..well-tought. I just don't know how to construct it...

Comment: @IvanM, I would recommend you to change the two digit year usage to four digits, that would save you from future troubles.

Comment: Thanks alot!! Isn't it better to set the startyear to the MIN of ACC2DATE and endyear to MAX of ACC2DATE? I'll just make the query, record it, and set it for $i = $startYearAccodingToQuery...right?

Comment: No never mind. This code is generated before the ACC2DATE is even posted to DB. I'll just do this! Thanks alot! I'll give it a try now.

Comment: Yes, preset MIN and MAX to MIN/MAX years in the DB, that would be smart of you. :) @IvanM

Comment: Somehow the code's not working. It keeps regenerating 01 every time. The query is 100% good. Can't find the problem in the code.

Comment: Send me the `PHP` file @IvanM

Comment: new here, i cant see any send nor ur email or any like that information.

Comment: for ($i = $formatdatefrom; $i <= 99; $i++)
 {
  $projectcount="
    SELECT accountingcode.custid, accountingcode.acc2date, COUNT(acc3nrofproj) as 'projects'
    FROM accountingcode, customer
    WHERE accountingcode.custid= customer.custid
    AND customer.custid = '$custid'
    AND acc2date = '$i'
    ";

  $result3=mysql_query($projectcount) or die("query fout " . mysql_error() );
  while( $record3=mysql_fetch_array($result3) )
  {
   $projectcount=$record3['projects'];
   $projectcount = $projectcount+1;
   $format = '%1$03s';
   $formatprojectcount = sprintf($format, $projectcount);
  }
 }

Comment: @IvanM, use dropbox or mediafire or some other file sharing service.

Comment: AHHH! I got it. This is it............  $projectcount="
    SELECT accountingcode.custid, accountingcode.acc2date, MAX(acc3nrofproj) as 'projects'
    FROM accountingcode, customer
    WHERE accountingcode.custid= customer.custid
    AND customer.custid = '$custid'
    AND acc2date = '$formatdatefrom'
    ";

  $result3=mysql_query($projectcount) or die("query fout " . mysql_error() );
  while( $record3=mysql_fetch_array($result3) )
  {
   $projectcount=$record3['projects'];
   $projectcount = $projectcount+1;
   $format = '%1$03s';
   $formatprojectcount = sprintf($format, $projectcount);
  }